# Using Workbooks.Open when file has 'unreadable content' / VBS

Tags: excel, file-io, vbscript, vba

Below a VBS code converts .xls into .csv.

```
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sfile)
    oBook.SaveAs fulldest, 6
    oBook.Close False
```

If works fine for most files but one of them has the usual `Excel found unreadable content in filename.xls'. do you want to recover the contents of this workbook ? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.`.

When the `.Workbooks.Open` method executes for this file, I get `Unable to get the Open property of the Workbooks`.

I tried `oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sfile, xlRepairFile)` without success.

Comment: What is the value of `csv_format`?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout. sorry, its 6

Comment: BTW are you referring to the error which you get on `Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(sfile)` or after saving and then manually opening the csv?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout. In the open statement! I don't know why win decided that the one file has unreadable content but when I open the file manually I just have to say the I trust the source and it works. I suppose I should be able to do just the same in the `Workbooks.Open` statement.

Comment: Hmm that shouldn't be happening if you can open the file manually.

Comment: Checked again and its for sure related to the `unreadable content`. My (non) solution up to now was use `on error resume next`.

Comment: may I see a sample file which is giving you the trouble?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Trouble is the file has plenty of private info which I'm sure has nothing to do with the issue but, whenever I save the file the bug is gone. I was hoping I could find a sample 'unreadable content' file online but nothing...